# Python script with BeautifulSoup downloading empty zip files

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, zip

I am trying to collectively retrieve hydrological measurement data using Python. Unfortunately, I get empty zip files downloaded every time.

here goes my code, done based on some YT tutorials:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

domain = "https://danepubliczne.imgw.pl/"
URL = 'https://danepubliczne.imgw.pl/data/dane_pomiarowo_obserwacyjne/dane_hydrologiczne/dobowe/2021/'
filetype = '.zip'


def get_soup(url):
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')


for link in get_soup(URL).find_all('a'):
    zip_link = link.get('href')
    if filetype in zip_link:
        print(zip_link)
        with open(link.text, 'wb') as file:
            response = requests.get(domain + zip_link)
            file.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is here:

`response = requests.get(domain + zip_link)`

The domain variable is the base url of the web site, but the links are relative to the sub directory. If you add

`print(domain + zip_link)`

You can see that you get something like https://danepubliczne.imgw.pl/codz_2021_01.zip

It looks like what you want is
`response = requests.get(URL + zip_link)`